# Daedalus Node is Not the Latest Version

Tags: daedalus, node, vasil-hard-fork

I am running Daedalus to use the Cardano-Cli. Right now when I run the command

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

It returns this, which states that it is still in the Alonzo era.

```
{
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "epoch": 214,
    "hash": "add989729d61973bb82174179887a089ae9648b28d211e9cfc83993aed3b7068",
    "block": 3680416,
    "slot": 62504629,
    "syncProgress": "99.74"
}
```

Do I have to update the node myself? Or do I have to wait for Daedalus to do it and download a newer release? If so, when will the updated version be out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be an updated version of Daedalus for testnet running the new node by the end of the week *(most likely Thursday, taken from [Discord](https://discord.com/channels/826816523368005654/868025141668503582/993558968968421437))*. You can probably download it from here once it's ready:

https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/get-started/wallet/

Answer (score 0):

let the node sync

the output you shared shows

```
    "syncProgress": "99.74"
```

meaning the node is not synced with the blockchain.

as soon running the command you see

```
   "syncProgress": "100.00"
```

you should be able to enjoy your Vasil testnet